# Drop duplicate times, but keep max value xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

There are several different solutions out there on how to drop duplicate times in an xarray dataset or dataaray. However, I have not seen any questions or examples that depict dropping times based on the value. I want to preferentially drop times and only keep the maximum value for that time.

My data is comprised of two dataarrays: `data1` contains data at 12 hourly resolution for July 2020, `data2` contains data at 24 hourly resolution for July 2020.

```
data1
xarray.DataArray 'tp' (time:62, latitude:137, longitude:261)

data2
xarray.DataArray 'tp' (time:31, latitude:137, longitude:261)
```

I tried doing something I thought might work for this solution in a round about way using a loop like this:

```
test=xr.concat([data1, data2], dim='time')
max_vals=[]
for i in test['time']:
    print(i)
    max_=test.sel(time=i).max(dim='time').expand_dims(time=[i])
    max_vals.append(max_)
```

What I thought/wanted to happen was that the `.sel()` command would select all times that corresponded to the time currently selected in the loop. In this specific example, there should be two values on times that are at hour 00, but only one at hour 12. However, it threw an error. Any thoughts or ideas on how to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note sure to fully understand the behaviour of the merge you want. What I understood is that you have `ds1` and `ds2` with overlapping time indexes, and you want a `ds` that is a merge of `ds1` and `ds2`, and which provides `max(ds1, ds2)` for the overlapping index ?

In this case, you could write :

```
ds = xr.concat([ds1, ds2], dim='new_dim').max(dim='new_dim')
```

Did I correctly understood your question ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think of doing it this way. Very nice.